# snprintf : simple way to force . as radix?

Tags: c, printf, radix

My program was not behaving correctly on one machine so I started to hunt for the bug, and I discovered that on that machine, snprintf uses a comma (,), not a . (dot) as 99% of other computers (at least in my experience).

Shouldn't this be standardized?

I am using a library that assumes that the radix is a . (dot) and so it does not work properly with a comma.

So my question is, is there a simple way to force the dot as the radix character? I know I could just search & replace the comma by a dot manually, but surely there is a cleaner way.

Comment: The computer is on 64-bit Ubuntu 10.04. The language setting is Czech in which ',' is indeed the radix character. However, this issue is in the "core" of the program, which has two UIs, a CLI and a GUI. If I compile the CLI only, it works fine (and uses the dot). If I compile it with GTK, it breaks and uses the comma.

Comment: `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "POSIX")` fixed it, great. Thanks both Doon and manneorama (accepting his, since I never worked with locales and his answer was more explicit).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to change your locale-setting using the `setlocale`-function to make snprintf use a dot. Try setting it to "POSIX" or "C". (`setlocale(LC_ALL, "POSIX")`

Comment: Thanks, I used `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "POSIX")` (thanks Doon also).

Answer (score 5):

`.` versus `,` is set by the `LC_NUMERIC` part of the locale.  So make sure you set your program to use a locale that uses the `.`  (such as `"POSIX"`).

Answer (score 1):

For library code, you may wish to use the POSIX 2008 `uselocale` function instead of `setlocale`. It is able to set a thread-specific locale, so that if your library code is called from a program that uses threads, it won't mess up the other threads' behavior (and/or crash the program, since `setlocale` is not thread-safe).

For application code, you should simply avoid ever setting the `LC_NUMERIC` locale category to anything but C/POSIX. The only categories you really need to set for most applications are `LC_CTYPE`, `LC_MESSAGES`, and possibly `LC_COLLATE`.