# C: What is the portable/safe(thread aware) way to convert a number to a string w/o locale settings?

Tags: c, locale, glibc

What is the safe/portable way to convert a number to a string (and the other way around) ?

I'm on Linux and my settings locale is so that when I use sprintf numbers have a "," instead of a "." as a separator.

Sometimes I want them that way, Sometimes not :)

I saw some solutions that imply playing with users settings. Clearly that's something one should not do. Somebody suggested using uselocale

[snprintf : simple way to force . as radix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457968/snprintf-simple-way-to-force-as-radix)

can someone elaborate a bit (looks like it's buggy on some glibc (<2.12)) and if possible provide some sample code (eg a macro SNPRINTF_POSIX).

I tried myself but my C skills are very limited.

[edit]

I find this code by [GO]Skywalker13 on Swisslinux.org after writing my question.
Any thoughts about it ? What about memory usage ? (I need to make numerous calls to this func)

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double
my_atof (const char *nptr)
{
  double res;
  locale_t new_locale;

  new_locale = newlocale (LC_NUMERIC_MASK, "C", NULL);
  res = strtod_l (nptr, NULL, new_locale);
  freelocale (new_locale);

  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With POSIX 2008, you can use the `newlocale` and `uselocale` functions to temporarily change the locale in the current thread without affecting other threads. This is really the only solution, aside from never setting the `LC_NUMERIC` locale category to begin with. On the other hand, I prefer banning use of `LC_NUMERIC` in software I write, at least for the global locale. Then you can use `newlocale` and `uselocale` locally at the point where you want numeric formatting that matches your user's cultural conventions, and on systems that lack POSIX 2008 `uselocale`, simply leave out localized numeric printing.