# How to parse numbers like "3.14" with scanf when locale expects "3,14"

Tags: c++, c, parsing, scanf

Let's say I have to read a file, containing a bunch of floating-point numbers. The numbers can be like `1e+10`, `5`, `-0.15` etc., i.e., any generic floating-point number, using decimal points (*this is fixed!*). However, my code is a plugin for another application, and I have no control over what's the current locale. It may be Russian, for example, and the LC_NUMERIC rules there call for a decimal *comma* to be used. Thus, Pi is expected to be spelled as "3,1415...", and

```
sscanf("3.14", "%f", &x);
```

returns "1", and x contains "3.0", since it refuses to parse past the '.' in the string.

I need to ignore the locale for such number-parsing tasks.

How does one do that?

I could write a parseFloat function, but this seems like a waste.
I could also save the current locale, reset it temporarily to "C", read the file, and restore to the saved one. What are the performance implications of this? Could setlocale() be very slow on some OS/libc combo, what does it really do under the hood?
Yet another way would be to use iostreams, but again their performance isn't stellar.

Comment: let's start with simple stuff, that can't be found by googling: what type is x?

Comment: @atk: This is not at all "simple stuff". I think you missed the whole point of the question.

Comment: @atk: it doesn't matter for the purposes of the question, but it's a float.

Comment: @anrieff: of course it matters!  If the type won't store the value you want it to, you won't get the result you want!

Comment: @R: Yeah, I probably did.  But before I spend my time researching something, I'd rather make sure that the basics are covered.

Comment: @atk: it's hard to make this kind of an error these days — the compilers detect it and produce a warning :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C: What is the portable/safe(thread aware) way to convert a number to a string w/o locale settings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980100/c-what-is-the-portable-safethread-aware-way-to-convert-a-number-to-a-string-w)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I've done with this stuff in the past.

The goal is to use locale-dependent numeric converters with a C-locale numeric representation. The ideal, of course, would be to use non-locale-dependent converters, or not change the locale, etc., etc., but sometimes you just have to live with what you've got. Locale support is seriously broken in several ways and this is one of them.</rant>

First, extract the number as a string using something like the `C` grammar's simple pattern for numeric preprocessing tokens. For use with scanf, I do an even simpler one:

```
" %1[-+0-9.]%[-+0-9A-Za-z.]"
```

This could be simplified even more, depending on how what else you might expect in the input stream. The only thing you need to do is to not read beyond the end of the number; as long as you don't allow numbers to be followed immediately by letters, without intervening whitespace, the above will work fine.

Now, get the `struct lconv` (`man 7 locale`) representing the current locale using `localeconv(3)`. The first entry in that struct is `const char* decimal_point`; replace all of the `'.'` characters in your string with that value. (You might also need to replace `'+'` and `'-'` characters, although most locales don't change them, and the sign fields in the `lconv` struct are documented as only applying to currency conversions.) Finally, feed the resulting string through `strtod` and see if it passes.

This is not a perfect algorithm, particularly since it's not always easy to know how locale-compliant a given library actually is, so you might want to do some autoconf stuff to configure it for the library you're actually compiling with.

Comment: using `0-9` etc. in scanf invokes implementation-defined behaviour

Answer (score 8):

My personal preference is to never use `LC_NUMERIC`, i.e. just call `setlocale` with other categories, or, after calling `setlocale` with `LC_ALL`, use `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");`. Otherwise, you're completely out of luck if you want to use the standard library for printing or parsing numbers in a standared form for interchange.

If you're lucky enough to be on a POSIX 2008 conforming system, you can use the `uselocale` and `*_l` family of functions to make the situation somewhat better. There are at least 2 basic approaches:

1. Leave the default locale unset (at least the troublesome parts like `LC_NUMERIC`; `LC_CTYPE` should probably *always* be set), and pass a `locale_t` object for the user's locale to the appropriate `*_l` functions only when you want to present things to the user in a way that meets their own cultural expectations; otherwise use the default C locale.
2. Have your code that needs to work with data for interchange keep around a `locale_t` object for the C locale, and either switch back and forth using `uselocale` when you need to work with data in a standard form for interchange, or use the appropriate `*_l` functions (but there is no `scanf_l`).

Note that implementing your own floating point parser is **not easy** and is probably not the right solution to the problem unless you're an expert in numerical computing. Getting it right is very hard.

---

POSIX.1-2008 specifies isalnum_l(), isalpha_l(), isblank_l(), iscntrl_l(), isdigit_l(), isgraph_l(), islower_l(), isprint_l(), ispunct_l(), isspace_l(), isupper_l(), and isxdigit_l().

Comment: Yes, but as I said, I don't ever call setlocale() in my code. It's a plugin to a larger program, which in turn has set the locale beforehand. I can't do anything about it. If I don't preserve their locale as my plugin returns control to the original app, other breakages will inevitably occur.

Comment: Using the locale functions works in threaded systems; using `setlocale()` could mess up other threads working in parallel.

Comment: @anrieff: There's no safe way to save and restore the locale in plain C; when C11 added threads they neglected to add a thread-safe way to do this, leaving a gaping deficiency. If you have the `uselocale` function and related stuff, just use that.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure how to solve it in C.

But C++ streams (can) have a unique locale object.

```
std::stringstream  dataStream;
dataStream.imbue(std::locale("C"));

// Note: You must imbue the stream before you do anything wit it.
//       If any operations have been performed then an imbue() can
//       be silently ignored by the stream (which is a pain to debug).

dataStream << "3.14";
float   x;
dataStream >> x;
```

Comment: Thanks for this post, helped me a lot with another problem! But is there a typo? I guess it's `std::locale("C")`, with lowercase 'L' (`<locale>` header).

Comment: @ollo: Yes. Corrected.

Comment: Prefer `std::locale::classic()` over `std::locale("C")`.