# Converting char[] to float or double - c++

Tags: c++, type-conversion, atof

**UPDATE according to** [TNTFreaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9612076/tntfreaks) instructions answer.

I have a char variable data defined such as follow:

```
#define CMD_LEN 4
char data[CMD_LEN + 1];
float n1;

# I pass the data variable to `serial_read` function
n = serial_read(serial_fd, data, CMD_LEN, TIMEOUT);

# Here, the process goes to  serial_read function more below and
# after it return here again to follow ...


std::cout << "Data brought from serial_read method " << data << std::endl;

flush = tcflush(serial_fd, TCIOFLUSH);
//n = n*0.01f;

cout << "Applying sscanf " << std::endl;
sscanf(data, "%f", &n1);
printf("%.3f" "%s", n1, "  ");
n1 = atof(data) * 0.5f;
printf("%.3f", n1);
cout << "n1 value which have data turn it " << n1 << std::endl;
```

---

When the compiler check the `serial_read` function, enter to this process is:

*Note: I type this `serial_read` function only to illustration purposes in relation to workflow that follow my question in the  process with respect to `data` variable *

```
    int SerialDriver::serial_read(int serial_fd, char *data, int size, int timeout_usec)
{
    std::cout << "Enter to serial_read method " << std::endl;
    fd_set fds;
    struct timeval timeout;
    bool band = false;
    int count = 0;
    int ret;
    int n;

    //-- Wait for the data. A block of size bytes is expected to arrive
    //-- within the timeout_usec time. This block can be received as
    //-- smaller blocks.
    do
    {
        //-- Set the fds variable to wait for the serial descriptor
        FD_ZERO(&fds);
        FD_SET(serial_fd, &fds);

        //-- Set the timeout in usec.
        timeout.tv_sec = 0;
        timeout.tv_usec = timeout_usec;
        // std::cout << "timeouts establecidos " << std::endl;

        //-- Wait for the data
        ret = select(FD_SETSIZE, &fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
        //-- If there are data waiting: read it
        if (ret == 1)
        {
            //-- Read the data (n bytes)
            n = read(serial_fd, &data[count], 1);
            // read viene de sofa/src/applications/plugins/SofaPML/argumentParser.h
            std::cout << "Enter to read method to read hapkit data via serial port " << std::endl;

            if (band)
            {
                if (data[count] != ' ')
                {
                    if (data[count] == '\n')
                    {
                        data[count] = '\0';
                        return count;
                    }
                    //-- The number of bytes receives is increased in n
                    count += n;
                }
            }
            if (!band && data[count] == '\n')
            {
                band = true;
            }
            //-- The last byte is always a 0 (for printing the string data)
            data[count] = 0;
        }
        std::cout << "band value: " << band << " and data: " << data << std::endl;

        //-- Repeat the loop until a data block of size bytes is received or
        //-- a timeout occurs
    } while (count < size && ret == 1);

    //-- Return the number of bytes reads. 0 If a timeout has occurred.
    std::cout << "Leaving serial_read method " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "count value " << count << std::endl;
    return count;

}
```

---

When  `serial_read` function finish,  `data` is returned and have the char value like by example `1.86`

I want to convert it that to float using `atof()` such as I type the code section  at the beginning code of my question and store the result on n1 variable
but the output that I get is:

```
Data brought from serial_read method 1.86
Applying sscanf 
1,000  0,500n1 value which have data turn it 0.5
Serial Driver draw n1: 0.5 1
1,000
```

The 1,000 value is the `data` value which I get that is 1.86, but atof remove the decimal parts or not include the foat data.

In summary is possible that I am not passing of a well way the parameter to `atof` function, (my `n1` variable is float ).
With respect to `sscanf` function, I am passing &n1 to sscanf like a a reference parameter to data to this be converted with `atof`, but this doesn't works

I get the same result.
I was thinking that is possible, although I understand the [TNTFreaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9612076/tntfreaks) instructions I am not apply it of a correct way?

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `char data="6.35";` won't  compile. It's unclear what you are asking about.

Comment: The problem is your locale. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13919817/sscanf-and-locales-how-does-one-really-parse-things-like-3-14

Comment: Are you sure you put the code into the question correctly? I get compilation errors whatever I do to the code: https://godbolt.org/g/GQ86Nk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sscanf() and locales. How does one really parse things like "3.14"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13919817/sscanf-and-locales-how-does-one-really-parse-things-like-3-14)

Comment: Most implementations don't support it yet, but locale-independent parsing is now part of the C++17 standard library: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars.

Comment: @DanielH and @-NeilButterworth it's true, **I've updated** my answer in relation to the data value just in case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, `char` is a type of variable that can only contain one or an array of characters not a string of characters. You may mean `const char* data = "6.35"` which is a c style string and what the `atof()` function requires as input. I would only use `data` as a `const char*` if you do not follow my recommendation below and still want to use `sscanf()` instead of `cin`.

In c++ using strings is easier than using `const char*` or char arrays. I would declare data as a string, get the input, and then convert it into a `const char*` using `c_str()` so `atof()` can use it.

`atof` returns a double not a float so you should declare n1 as a double.

I recommend not using a mixture of c and c++ commands (i. e. `cout` and `sscanf()`). It will compile in c++ if the syntax is correct, but I think it will be easier for you to use `cin` instead of `sscanf()`.

You may also want to tell the compiler to assume the standard namespace (std) so you don't have to write `std::` in front of all your `cout`'s, `cin`'s, `endl`'s, etc.

Example:

```
#include <cstdlib> //atof
#include <iostream>   //cout, cin, endl
#include <string> //string, c_str()

using namespace std;   //now you don't have to write std::cout

int main() {
    float n1;
    string data;

    cin >> data;   //get input
    n1 = atof(data.c_str());   //convert data to const char* and make it a float
    cout << "Original data: " << data << endl;   //output
    cout << "Result: " << n1;
}
```

**Updated, more intelligent, more useful answer:**

These are just some things I took note of while doing some tests of my own.

1. Don’t use double, use float. Double didn’t work in my research.
2. When you used %.3f you were showing 3 decimal places of a whole number, hence why you get 6.000
3. `n1 = sscanf(data, "%f", n1)` is not correct. It will compile, but the program should crash. (It did for me). First, `sscanf()` does not return the float found in data. It returns the number of variables filled so it will not result in what you intend. Second, `n1` needs to be made a reference parameter for this to work. You want to edit the original variable `n1` not make a copy of it. Correct syntax would be: `sscanf(data, "%f", &n1);`

Example:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char data[5] = "6.35";
    float n1;

    sscanf(data, "%f", &n1);
    printf("%.3f" "%s", n1, "  ");
    n1 = atof(data);
    printf("%.3f", n1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `sscanf` function is not just the C equivalent to `cin`, or anything like that. You could simplify `scanf` as that, but `sscanf` works on data already existing in the program memory, not on standard input. It's more like the equivalent of stringstreams, except stringstreams have quite a bit more runtime overhead in many (most? all?) cases.

Comment: declare data as a string it's a good idea, but the `char data` variable that I declare is of this way `char data[CMD_LEN + 1];` (**I've updated a few my question ... just in case please**), and this `data`  variable is passed to `serial_read` function and here it's a pointer who receive this parameter. Then declare data like string it's not alternative for me ... :(

Comment: @bgarcial I lost my notes on this question, but I typed what I could remember. I will update more as I find things/remember them.

Comment: @TNTFreaks if you need some information about it,  I will be pending.

Comment: Hi @TNTFreaks I am follow the instructions that you orient me, but my result is the same applying `n1` like reference parameter to `sscanf(data, "%f", &n1);` My `atof` function does not convert to float the `data` value. **I've updated my question** about of that process of follow my `data` variable and I've trying check what is that happenning, but I ignore if I am applying well your instructions. Your support will be highly appreciated

Comment: Including "using namespace std;" is [considered bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: I am curious as to how/why the double didn't work in your research. I'll brush up on types but I'd still be interested in understanding why this happened.

Comment: @Jouster500 me too actually

Comment: @bgarcial the code worked for me. I will continue to look into this. Sorry I took so long to respond, I have had finals that finish today.

Comment: @TNTFreaks of a separate way, the code works, but including with my serial_read function and the workflow process that I mention above, does not work. Your answer only it's works

Comment: @bgarcial hmmm. Ok then you may not be correctly diagnosing what part of your code is causing the problem. Can you provide a link for the full code? Google Drive or something ?

Comment: On this file, I have the [serial_read](https://github.com/christiandiazleon/SimDesign_SOFA/blob/ZeroMQSerialComAllInOne/applications/plugins/ZeroMQCommunication/SerialDriver.cpp#L341) function which read data from serial port of some device connected. Next, the obtained data I want turn it on float, due to `serial_read ` function return it like `char` data type [here](https://github.com/christiandiazleon/SimDesign_SOFA/blob/ZeroMQSerialComAllInOne/applications/plugins/ZeroMQCommunication/SerialDriver.cpp#L354) and it's here in where `atof` doesm't works.

Comment: As additional data, I am using  gcc 5.4.0 version C++ compiler. It's strange this,  it seems that the standard c ++ libraries in this case `atof` does not works. I haven't another reason or explanation.

Comment: Hi @TNTFreaks I've replaced `atof`  standard c++ library function by `stof` customized function which [is here](https://gist.github.com/bgarcial/5f8c64ed091f0ea7e5fa1361efddcc99#file-cpp-L7) and using `stof` instead `atof`, I get the decimal part.

Comment: Yes, now, perform the convert to char to float.

Comment: Explain further please. So is everything you need answered? @bgarcial

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/bgarcial/5f8c64ed091f0ea7e5fa1361efddcc99#file-cpp-L7) I've used the `stof` custom function which turn the `char` data to `float`. In my code, I use the `stof` function instead of `atof`: [I implement the stof function here](https://github.com/christiandiazleon/SimDesign_SOFA/blob/ZeroMQSerialCommDeformation/applications/plugins/ZeroMQCommunication/SerialDriver.cpp#L332)  and I use the `stof` function of this [way](https://github.com/christiandiazleon/SimDesign_SOFA/blob/ZeroMQSerialCommDeformation/applications/plugins/ZeroMQCommunication/SerialDriver.cpp#L381)

Comment: For the moment that is all I need.