# Does this KHR_debug output mean <1ms or 147ms?

Tags: debugging, opengl, warnings

I've enabled GL debug logging in my app, and getting messages such as:

> GTT mapping a busy miptree BO stalled and took 0,147 ms

Initially I took the numeral to mean a sub-millisecond delay. Since there's a 0 before the comma, I didn't consider the interpretation "147ms", but [this page](https://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/writing/comma?01) says:

> Don’t use commas in decimals.

... so it can't be a decimal fraction either.

So which is the correct interpretation?

**Note:** I use Ubuntu Linux and my regional settings are as follows:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, a period is set to used to separate the fractional part of the number.

Comment: Doesn't that entirely depend on your language? In german language, for example, a comma would be the correct separator.

Comment: @BDL: Please see my edit. My system is set to use the US region, although I live in Bulgaria, which uses a comma for separating the fractional part.

Comment: Check the output of the `locale` command on some terminal. I wouldn't trust that setting screen at all, especially when the grayed-out detailed settings still show `bg_BG`. The message you are experiencing comes from mesa, and tracking it down leads to it being generated via `vsnprintf(...,"%.03fms", ..., value_in_milliseconds);`, which means that the locale settings should apply unless your libc is broken. Also note that broken applications might change parts of the locale setting by themselves.

Comment: [`perf_debug("%s a busy \"%s\" BO stalled and took %.03f ms.\n", action, bo->name, elapsed * 1000);`](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/tree/src/mesa/drivers/dri/i965/brw_bufmgr.c#n685)

Comment: `perf_debug()` (eventually) maps down to [`vsnprintf()`](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/tree/src/mesa/main/imports.c#n259)

Comment: Does [`setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "POSIX")`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3458045/44729) work?

Comment: @genpfault: I tried that setlocale call (right in the beginning of `main()`), but it didn't change anything.

Comment: @derhass: Thanks, `locale`'s output indeed says `LC_NUMERIC=bg_BG.UTF-8` - that's likely to be the culprit. Now I'd just like to know how to fix it :)

Comment: @derhass: Ok, got it fixed and posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [derhass' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45311511/does-this-khr-debug-output-mean-1ms-or-147ms#comment77586041_45311511) I found that `locale`'s output says `LC_NUMERIC=bg_BG.UTF-8`. I changed the relevant value in `/etc/default/locale` to `en_US.UTF-8`and now a period is used, as expected. So it's indeed a sub-millisecond value.

**Note:** That's the only way I was able to get it fixed. Nothing I did in the KDE settings page (shown in a screenshot in the question) helped.

Answer (score 0):

How a driver decides what decimal mark to use is implementation-defined (*all* of the debug output messages are implementation-defined). It may follow your locale settings; it may follow something else. As such, there is no way to guarantee how it formats numbers.

It could be either, though if it is intended as a comma rather than a decimal mark, what would the zero mean?